# Objective-C PFQuery retrieving strings

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm fairly new to objective-C so excuse my probably ugly code, but at the moment I have the following function to retrieve objects from parse which I then intend to use to populate a list view in Xcode.

-(void) retrieveEventsFromParse {

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"events"];

//retrieve all columns (will be fixed once a userId value is added)
[query whereKey:@"location" notEqualTo:@""];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // The find succeeded.

        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu locations.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {

            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

}

However I can only seem to retrieve the objectId, instead I want to retrieve a value called 'location' which is stored as a string. How would I go about doing this?

sorry I am very new to this so if you could be specific in examples that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks okay.  Just to get started, skip the `whereKey` qualification to make sure you can get some objects.  Use the `objectForKey:` method on `PFObject` to access the value of columns...

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"events"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu locations.", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            // assuming location is a string, change the type if it isn't
            NSString *location = [object objectForKey:@"location"];
            NSLog(@"object with id has location %@ %@", object.objectId, location);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```